# Not able to install dompdf on Laravel Framework version 5.1.10 (LTS)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have changed in composer.json file "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*" but after updating composer I got the following error:

> php artisan clear-compiled
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.19
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.18
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.17
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.16
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.15
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.14
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.13
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.12
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.11
>   - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.1.10
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.10
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.9
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.8
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.7
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.6
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.5
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.4
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.3
>   - Installation request for braunson/laravel-html5-forms dev-master -> satisf
>   iable by braunson/laravel-html5-forms[dev-master].
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.2
>   - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.1
>   - braunson/laravel-html5-forms dev-master requires illuminate/support 4.2.*
>   -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2,
>   v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5
>   .1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.12|don't install laravel/framework v
>   5.1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.16|don't install laravel/framework v
>   5.1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.17|don't install laravel/framework v
>   5.1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5
>   .1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v5
>   .1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.4|don't install laravel/framework v5
>   .1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.5|don't install laravel/framework v5
>   .1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5
>   .1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5
>   .1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.8|don't install laravel/framework v5
>   .1.0
>   - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework v5
>   .1.0
>   - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel
>   /framework[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.10, v5.1.11, v5.1.12, v5.1.13, v5.1.14, v5.1.15,
>   v5.1.16, v5.1.17, v5.1.18, v5.1.19, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.
>   1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9].

Answer (score 0):

Those messages are telling you that the set of packages you have installed are not compatible with one another.

Composer packages keep track of their dependencies - if package A requires package X version 1.0, and package B requires package X version 2.0, composer will not be able to install any of the packages, because it cannot install two different versions of package X.

The solution: remove the package that's causing the conflict. In the text above, you've left out some of the info, so I can't see what package is causing it. But judging from your description, it's probably the DOMPDF package. Remove that, and check if there's a different version that is compatible with your version of Laravel.

Comment: Is there any package for html to pdf converter which  is compatible for laravel 5.1.10